# What is the difference between Adapters and Modules in MORYX?

Tags: c#, moryx

In the context of *MORYX*, I recently heard/read about *Adapters* and *Modules* being used in similar situations.

When browsing through the [framework](https://github.com/PHOENIXCONTACT/MORYX-Framework) I can find a representation of Modules (`IModule`), also `IPlugin` which might go in the same direction, but it appears as there is nothing to represent an *Adapter*.

If not used synonymously, what is the difference between *Adapters* and *Modules*?

Answer (score 0):

Modules and Adapters are the same thing under the hood. Both are components in a MORYX application, which might by extended and configured through the `ModuleConfig` and implementations of `IPlugin`.

However, by splitting up the two conceptually we get a better transparency of responsibilities. Conceptually speaking, **Modules** encapsulate a specific functionality that only utilizes internal facades and or UIs. **Adapters** on the other hand, always utilize an IT system to fullfill their functionality. We label components which communicate externally as adapters and, thus, highlight them as connections to other systems.